# update id column by referencing on date column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `datetime` column in the following format:

```
2018-02-25 13:44:45
```

I want to set ALL `id` values as reference on `date` values.

In the above example `id` should be:

180225134445

So I need to remove `20` from the start and all spaces etc. in the rest.`

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DATE_FORMAT` like so:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%y%m%d%H%m%s");
```

So for an `update` statement for a `table` with `id, post_date` columns it'd be:

```
UPDATE table SET id = DATE_FORMAT(post_date, "%y%m%d%H%m%s");
```

For more info, check out the w3schools guide [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Comment: how can I do this for ALL rows. Something like: `update posts set id = new-value-from-date-column`

Comment: Added another snippet for that scenario